# How do i add a information for my functions defined in a .NET DLL

Tags: .net, attributes, xml-documentation

How do I add XML documentation for Methods in c# that comes in .NET functions.

**Example**

> Guid.NewGuid();

when user press . key he gets a help about the function NewGuid what it does.

I have a class GetDocsInfo which have functions like getDocTag and I need a similar functionality, is there any meta data kind of things I need to add just like attributes

Comment: [check this link.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-documentation-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is simply the intellisense that is shown. This is extracted from the comment metadata for the function or property, i.e.:

```
/// <summary>
/// My details here....
/// </summary>
public void MyFunction()
{
    ... etc ...
}
```

If you put the editing cursor on the line above the function you want to document, then type three consecutive forward slashes, Visual Studio will then auto populate the comment section for you, all you have to do is insert the details.

Alternatively, you could use a Visual Studio plugin called [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), which gives you an option in your context menu to automatically document the function - it does a reasonable job of determining what the documentation should be based on the parameters and the name of the function.

Comment: i have added the /// for the summary but it is not showing ,i have build the library too

Comment: my functions have many parameters more than 10 and when i choose any function it shows the list of all parameters and shows what this function returns

Answer (score 0):

You need to add XML documentation for class members. While you type code in Visual studio press / key three times in the line just about your member definition and a skeleton will be generated which you can edit.

```
/// <summary>
/// What your function does.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="paramterName">Description of parameter</param>
public void Method Name(string paramterName)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand it correctly because its a very common thing to do in C# but if you are using C#, the triple slashes can be used to generate documentation for a function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds two numbers
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">First number</param>
/// <param name="y">Second number</param>
/// <returns>The sum of specified numbers</returns>
private int Sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by writing '///' above ur function or class

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-documentation-generator